# Get Public Key from SSL Certificate in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, pem

I'm using [get-ssl-certificate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-ssl-certificate) to get an SSL Certificate from an auth server. It works, and brings me back a JSON object with info from the our auth server. but I need a PEM encoded public key string to finish my authorization. I don't know how to convert the object I got, though, into the right format.

Is there any way to do this easily in Node?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @ashic Yes, I just added an answer that you can see now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the package mentioned above, [get-ssl-certificate](https://github.com/pjlamb12/get-ssl-certificate), to get the information from the auth server. It comes back with a `raw` attribute, which I converted to a base64 string, and then format. Here's what I did:

```
if (certificate.raw) {
    certificate.pemEncoded = pemEncode(certificate.raw.toString('base64'), 64);
}
...

// pemEncode function:

function pemEncode(str, n) {
    const ret = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
        ret.push(str[i - 1]);
        const mod = i % n;

        if (mod === 0) {
        ret.push('\n');
        }
    }
    const returnString = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ${ret.join('')}-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;
    return returnString;
}
```

That worked for me. I submitted this code as a PR to the library, and hopefully it will soon be included as part of the library. In the meantime, this is what we are using and it is working well.

Comment: Your code works for me if I add the following line after the for loop:   if   (ret[ret.length - 1] != '\n') {
    ret.push('\n');
  }